# update div in ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

i have written my codes by ajax as following : instead of updating div,has redirected to partial view.
according to update target id of ajax option is set,it cant update.
please help me

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult search()
   {
       return View();
   }

    public PartialViewResult _search()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        ViewBag.message = "test";
        return PartialView("_search");
    }

}
@{
ViewBag.Title = "search";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>search</h2>


@Ajax.ActionLink("Click",
             "_search",
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                         UpdateTargetId = "_search",
                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                         HttpMethod = "GET"
                     }
            )

 <div id="_search">

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have following scripts added into either of your view or masterview

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
MicrosoftAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click",
             "_search",
              null,
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                         UpdateTargetId = "_search",
                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                         HttpMethod = "GET"
                     }
            )
```